# Add summary of selected points in the caption in leaflet

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

I am trying to show a leaflet map using R(I can not use ShinyApp package).
I want to show mean of a column for selected points in leaflet caption(or anywhere in map) as following image shows:

[image]

This is my try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet) 
library(DT)
library(crosstalk)

data_2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1:8),
                 Name1 = c("A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B"),
                 Name2 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"),
                 Value1 = c(12,43,54,34,23,77,44,22),
                 Value2 = c(6,5,2,7,5,6,4,3),
                 Lat = c(51.1, 51.6, 57.3, 52.4, 56.3, 54.3, 60.4, 49.2),
                 Lon = c(5, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 0))
data_2<-data_2 %>%
  mutate(
lab_DB = case_when(
  Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[1]  ~ "blue",
  Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[2]  ~ "green",
  Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[3]  ~  "red"
  
    )
  )
data_2$ID <- as.character(data_2$ID)
sdf <- SharedData$new(data_2, ~data_2$ID)
ltlf5<- leaflet(sdf) %>% 
  #addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
               lng = ~Lat,
               lat = ~Lon,
               group = ~Name1,popup = ~paste(Name1, '   <br/>  ',
                                                Name2,'   <br/>  ' ),
               color =~lab_DB ,
               radius = 3
 )   %>%
 addLayersControl(

overlayGroups = c('A','B','C')
,options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  addLegend(
position = 'bottomleft',
labels = c('Group A','Group B','Group C'),
colors = c("blue","red", "green"),
title = "number of observation"
  ) 
bscols(ltlf5 ,
datatable(sdf , width = "100%",editable=TRUE,caption = paste("mean of Value1:",mean(sdf$data()$Value1)))
)
```

But unfortunately It shows the mean of column 'Value1' not the mean of column 'Value1' for selected points. So how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are looking for is SummaryWidget:

https://kent37.github.io/summarywidget

install with:

```
devtools::install_github("kent37/summarywidget")
```

This is very easy to use if you wan't the summary statistic to be in an Rmarkdown document paragraph, as shown in the link above. But to have it in the caption of a datatable is a little more difficult.

Honestly I find crosstalk a nightmare to work with. It never seems to work how I would want and doesn't have the flexibility you would expect.
Below is a disgusting hack to get this in the caption of a datatable. Don't try and understand it, I don't. You have to install shiny for this to work as there is a function we need from it.

There is almost certainly a better way of doing this if anyone else wants to try XD

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet) 
library(DT)
library(crosstalk)
library(summarywidget)
library(shiny) # <- SHINY 

data_2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1:8),
                     Name1 = c("A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B"),
                     Name2 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"),
                     Value1 = c(12,43,54,34,23,77,44,22),
                     Value2 = c(6,5,2,7,5,6,4,3),
                     Lat = c(51.1, 51.6, 57.3, 52.4, 56.3, 54.3, 60.4, 49.2),
                     Lon = c(5, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 0))
data_2<-data_2 %>%
  mutate(
    lab_DB = case_when(
      Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[1]  ~ "blue",
      Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[2]  ~ "green",
      Name1 == unique(data_2$Name1)[3]  ~  "red"
      
    )
  )
data_2$ID <- as.character(data_2$ID)
sdf <- SharedData$new(data_2, ~ID)
ltlf5<- leaflet(sdf) %>% 
  #addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    lng = ~Lat,
    lat = ~Lon,
    group = ~Name1,popup = ~paste(Name1, '   <br/>  ',
                                  Name2,'   <br/>  ' ),
    color =~lab_DB ,
    radius = 3
  )   %>%
  addLayersControl(
    
    overlayGroups = c('A','B','C')
    ,options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  addLegend(
    position = 'bottomleft',
    labels = c('Group A','Group B','Group C'),
    colors = c("blue","red", "green"),
    title = "number of observation"
  ) 
bscols(widths=c(6,6,0),ltlf5 ,
       datatable(sdf , width = "100%",editable=TRUE, caption=tags$caption("Mean of Value1: ",summarywidget(sdf, statistic='mean', column='Value1'))), 
       htmltools::p(summarywidget(sdf, statistic='mean', column='Value1'), style="display:none;")
      )
```

Comment: Is it possible to select marker by lasso in leaflet in R like https://github.com/zakjan/leaflet-lasso ?